# reaver and WPS problems

Tags: kali-linux

I'm trying this command with reaver :

`reaver -i wlan0mon -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  -d 90 -S -N -vv`

and getting

`[!] WARNING: Detected AP rate limiting, waiting 60 seconds before re-checking`

(WPS in AP turns locked until restarted) or

```
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[!] WARNING: 25 successive start failures
```

with every AP I tried. Is there something wrong with the command or is this normal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with WPS Pin attacks and contemporary Access Points for a few years now.

The Kali forums have extensive threads on the topic, such as this excellent one:

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?19641-Reaver-WPS-Locked-Situation-and-Useful-Link

I've personally given up on WPS attacks and had more success with conventional WPA attacks using Aircrack streamlined with the Fern frontend.

Fern also has a WPS checkbox and reports whether the AP is WPS enabled, but it's just as slow as the locking you're experiencing with Reaver.

Comment: ok, thx. Will check the forum.

Comment: Have you had any success with fern, I suppose you are using a wordlist

Comment: @alfred Fern works for WPA attacks, it's just an Aircrack-ng frontend and if you elect "Show xTerm Windows", you'll get to see real time airomon-ng consoles. The proximity to the target and wattage makes all the difference and elevation is underappreciated since a few feet of elevation can be the same as another 1/2 watt of power. But it's been a long time since I've had a successful WPS attack. I prefer ALFA and TPLink external adapters in USB powered hubs for best placement in places like window sills.